# How to avoid multiple event listeners from being attached?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

Is the following code going to attach multiple event listeners or will React Native / expo-linking only allow one event listener be attached at a time?

```
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking'
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
    Linking.addEventListener('url', _handleEvent)
  }, [isFocused])

  const fetchData = () => {
    // ...
  }

  const _handleEvent = () => {
    // ...
  }

  return (
    <View><View>
  )
}
```

Is there are a way to check if an event listener already exists so I can do something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
  if(!eventListenerExists){
    Linking.addEventListener('url', _handleEvent)
  }
}, [isFocused])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll attach multiple handlers, adding one each time `isFocused` changes. To remove the previous handler when attaching the next, return a function that React will call:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
  Linking.addEventListener('url', _handleEvent)
  return () => Linking.removeEventListener('url', _handleEvent) // <======
}, [isFocused])
```

You want to do that **anyway** so that the handler is removed when your component is completely unmounted.

This is covered in the React documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect).

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think even should call one time

```
useEffect(() => {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', _handleEvent)
  return () => Linking.removeEventListener('url', _handleEvent) // <======
}, [])
```

Comment: I still need to call `fetchData()` when `isFocused` value changes though. This doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

1、in the useEffect callback, return the function that remove the listener;
2、every time remove the listener before bind it.
such as:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('url', hander);
    window.addEventListener('url', hander);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('url', hander);
}, [XXX])
```